# jQuery alert is returning code

Tags: jquery, html, alert

I'm using the following HTML and JavaScript to display the value of the `#username` `<input>` element:

```
<form action="#" method="post">
  Username: <input type="text" name="username" /><br />
  Password: <input type="password" name="password" /><br />
  <input class="test" type="submit" id="thing" value="Log In" />
</form>
```

```javascript
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('input#thing').on('click', function() {
    var name = $('#username').val;
    alert(name);
  });
});​
```

When I run it in my browser, I get an alert saying

```
function (value) {
    var hooks, ret, isFunction, elem = this[0];
    if (!arguments.length) {
        if (elem) {
            hooks = jQuery.valHooks[elem.type] ||
                jQuery.valHooks[elem.nodeName.toLowerCase()];
            if (hooks &&
                "get" in hooks &&
                (ret = hooks.get(elem, "value")) !== undefined) {
                return ret;
            }
            ret = elem.value;
            return typeof ret === "string" ? ret.replace(rreturn, "") : ret == null ? "" : ret;
        }
        return;
    }
    isFunction = jQuery.isFunction(value);
    return this.each(function (i) {var val, self = jQuery(this);if (this.nodeType !== 1) {return;}if (isFunction) {val = value.call(this, i, self.val());} else {val = value;}if (val == null) {val = "";} else if (typeof val === "number") {val += "";} else if (jQuery.isArray(val)) {val = jQuery.map(val, function (value) {return value == null ? "" : value + "";});}hooks = jQuery.valHooks[this.type] || jQuery.valHooks[this.nodeName.toLowerCase()];if (!hooks || !("set" in hooks) || hooks.set(this, val, "value") === undefined) {this.value = val;}});
}
```

When it should be saying what the typed username is.

What's happening?

Comment: `.val()` is a function, not a property.

Comment: Your question can't depend on external links to be useful. You need to include enough of your code in your question for it to be answerable and useful without external links.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following code assigns the *function* `val` to the variable `name`.

```
    var name = $('#username').val;
    alert(name);
```

You're then passing *the function* into `alert`. If you want to pass the value in the text box, you have to *invoke* the function and pass its return value:

```
    var name = $('#username').val();
    alert(name);
```

Comment: Thank you that worked! But why does it say the variable is undefined? Sorry for the noob question, I'm still getting the hang of jQuery

Comment: Because your element doesn't have an id of `username`. It has a *name* of `username`. If you want to access it via `#username`, you need to use `<input id="username" type="text" name="username" />`. That's what `#foo` syntax does - select an element by its ID.

Comment: Wow sorry, I would have known that, it just flew right over my head. You get the accepted answer.

Answer (score 5):

Use

```
$("#username").val();
```

instead of:

```
$("#username").val;
```

The entire contents of the `val` function are being alerted. Make sure to actually call the function (with `()`).

Answer (score 1):

You need to call the `val()` function. Change it to `$('#username').val();` (note the parentheses)

Just `.val` (without the parentheses) will give you the code of the function.

Also when you put a demo on jsfiddle, make sure to select the right framework. If you're using jQuery, select jQuery. Mootools is default and will cause your jQuery code to not work at all.